# How can I make sub-object searching more terse?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I am interested in a **terse** way to do a lookup for a match within an array that requires levels of sub-objects.  The performance does not have to be close to ideal but should be reasonable.

For this case *I do not want to add a reverse relationship or manage retained dictionaries*.  I don't want to change the model at all.

Object1 contains an Object2, and Object2 contains an Object3.  I understand that the following method will return the *first* match, however a solution that returns every match would also be acceptable.

```
-(Object1*)getObject1ForObject3:(Object3*)object3
{
    for(Object1 *object1 in self.object1s)
        if(object1.object2.object3 == object3)
            return  object1 ;

    return nil ;
}
```

And for prestige, can we make it terse if there is a to-many relationship in the middle?

```
-(Object1*)getObject1ForObject3:(Object3*)object3
{
    for(Object1 *object1 in self.object1s)
        for(Object2 *object2 in object1.object2s)
            if(object2.object3 == object3)
                return  object1 ;

    return nil ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the API for declaring an NSPredicate isn't exactly *terse*, but it's still probably more terse than what you're doing.

For the first case, where there's not a to-many in the middle:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"object2.object3 == %@", object3];
NSArray *matchingObj1s = [self.object1s filteredArrayUsingPredicate];
```

When there's a to-many relationship in the middle:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY object2s.object3 == %@", object3];
NSArray *matchingObj1s = [self.object1s filteredArrayUsingPredicate];
```

Comment: Very cool.  I could see this becoming a convenience category method like [self.object1s filteredArrayWhereKeyPath:@"object2.object3" equals:object3];

Comment: I have added -filteredArrayWhereKeyPath:equals: to NSArray in my refactoring library, https://github.com/peterdeweese/es_ios_utils